# jQuery and CSS div element change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now i am working a simple jQuery code when a click on button a jQuery function is called and inside this function i change css of a div.

Here is my code, take a look:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function SuperWebF1() 
 {
    $("#outerdiv").css({"border":"2px solid #e39f9f"});
    alert('SportsDirect.bg: Моля, първо посочете желания от Вас цвят!');

 }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="billing.save();SuperWebF1();"></button>

<div id="outerdiv"></div>
```

CSS of "outerdiv":

```
#outerdiv
{
   width:4000px;
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
   border:2px solid #fff;
}
```

When i place the `alert('SportsDirect.bg: Моля, първо посочете желания от Вас цвят!');` before the `$("#outerdiv").css({"border":"2px solid #e39f9f"});` the alert is working. But it's not working in the other way.

In all cases my CSS function is not working and this code is not changing the border CSS of the div element.

Where is my mistake guys?

After this code i also have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#SubmitButton").click(function() {
    $('.HeaderPostForm').hide();
    $('.PleaseWait').show();
    this.form.submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm giving this as a note..

Comment: Check your javascript console for errors. My guess would be that jquery is not loading successfully since your vanilla javascript is working.

Comment: I am using Opera how can i check the console ?

Comment: Why would you develop in Opera? It's one of the least used browsers. IMHO You should start in Chrome and test in others. Besides, again IMO chome has the best debugging features. Just hit F12 to open the debugger.

Comment: Chrome and Opera's developer tools should be almost identical these days, since Opera is now using the same engine as Chrome. You can open them on Windows using F12 or CMD+OPTION+I on a Mac. (assuming you are using a recent version of Opera)

Comment: What is `billing.save();`?

Comment: When i typed: `SuperWebF1()` in the console i received `TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null`. `billing.save();` Is removed and it's giving the same results...

Comment: Remove the line $.noConflict(); and then let us know.

Answer (score 0):

rather than using `onclick` why not add an event listener to the button by giving it an id and using that like so

```
<button type="button" id="btn">Button</button>
<div id="outerdiv"></div>

$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    $("#outerdiv").css({"border":"2px solid #e39f9f"});
    alert('SportsDirect.bg: Моля, първо посочете желания от Вас цвят!');

    // and add the functionality for the other click event in here too
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/1rk6eh7t/) showing it in action using this method